# Android, why shouldn't one Fragment call another directly?

Tags: android, android-fragments

According to Android guidline, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
One fragment should send data to another one via the hosting Activity. I'm wondering there is a reason for that. 
Since in my code, I put one variable to hold pointer to the another fragment, and assign it in onActivityCreated

```
//this code is in class FragmentType1, assign the pointer to the FragmentType2 for later use
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

                mOtherFragment = (FragmentType2) fm
                .findFragmentById(R.id.container_fragment);
    }
```

and later if I want to set data for FragmentType2, I just call:

```
public setData(MyData data){
    if (mOtherFragment!=null)
        mOtherFragment.setData(data); 
}
```

Everything is working fine now. What's wrong with that approach? Tks.

Comment: This is because we are trying to decouple things, and could probably reuse these fragments elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

There's at least 2 reasons for it:

- To facilitate de-coupling of fragments.
- To avoid memory leaks that can happen by storing a reference to one fragment in another.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason would be to maintain the state when the hosting activity is destroyed.

After recreation, you could fetch the state from the hosting activity, since the fragment itself would be unable to save it's state directly.

Answer (score 0):

And last but not least, it is really hard for dynamically added fragments, especially when it comes to nested fragments, to get sure that both fragments are "alive" at the same time. Fragments life cycle is complex to manage properly and using a direct communication presumes you completely control this, which is rarely true.

The best model to my mind is to use an event bus, like Otto or EventBus or RoboGuice's bus.